# UNIQUE KEY with one null field

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
- territory_id
- platform_id
- title_id (NULLable)
- collection_id (NULLable)
```

Here are a few values I have in table:

```
1 - ('US', 'ITUNES', 1, NULL)
2 - ('US', 'ITUNES', 1, NULL)
3 - ('US', 'ITUNES', NULL, 1)
```

1 and 2 are duplicates, and should not both be allowed. However, with the foreign key on the four above fields:

```
ALTER TABLE pricing ADD UNIQUE KEY (territory_id, platform_id, title_id, collection_id)
```

It still allows me to insert that, most likely because it ignores the integrity check if one of the fields is null. Is there a way of getting around this without create two unique keys, on `(territory_id, platform_id, title_id)` and `(territory_id, platform_id, colletion_id)`?

Comment: It is not ignoring an integrity check, NULL values are not considered equal to one another. Yes, it is annoying at times, but as far as I know, there is no way to tell MySQL to treat NULLs as the same for the purpose of UNIQUE constraints. Also, two unique keys are not actually equivalent, though they may serve you purposes. Is `(US, ITUNES, 1, 1)` a record that should be able to exist alongside your first values example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [MySQL bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8173) that is *not* a bug.

A few workarounds:

1. Set all fields to NOT NULL and use some special value to denote a NULL, set it as the default value, then make your program recognize that value. Hacky and error prone.
2. I'm guessing title_id and collection_id FK to something. If you have a null value in that table, you can insert that ID and avoid having a NULL. I like this, but could be inappropriate if a null ID is significant.
3. Maybe you could use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) somehow. You can make a trigger go BEFORE an action, so you could do something like check the table before the insert and if the row exists don't INSERT, or do something else.